# Can't printf with PeekPokeTester in Chisel3

Tags: scala, sbt, hdl, chisel

I'm trying to print some value when testing my chisel3 design with this testbench code :

```
package taptempo

import chisel3._
import chisel3.iotesters
import chisel3.iotesters.{ChiselFlatSpec, Driver, PeekPokeTester}
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

class TapTempoUnitTester(t: TapTempo) extends PeekPokeTester(t) {
  val tptmp = t


  printf("Begin of test\n")

  def pushbutton(button: Bool) {
   poke(button, 0)
   step(1)
   print("Push \n")
   poke(button, 1)
   step(10)
   poke(button, 0)
  }


  val tclk = tptmp.tclk_ns //ns

  val tms = 10*tclk
  val ts = 1000*tms

  for(i <- 0 to 6) {
    peek(tptmp.io.button)
    pushbutton(tptmp.io.button)
    step(1*tms)
  }

  printf("End of Test\n")

}


class TapTempoTester extends ChiselFlatSpec {
  behavior of "TapTempoTester"

  it should "launch a simple test" in {
    chisel3.iotesters.Driver(() => new TapTempo(100000)) {
      c => new TapTempoUnitTester(c)
    } should be(true)
  }
}
```

But I've got this error when launching testbench with command:

```
sbt 'test:runMain taptempo.TapTempoMain'
```

Error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /usr/local/opt/TapTempoChisel/project
[info] Set current project to TapTempo (in build file:/usr/local/opt/TapTempoChisel/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /usr/local/opt/TapTempoChisel/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[info] Running taptempo.TapTempoMain 
[info] [0,004] Elaborating design...
[info] [1,018] Done elaborating.
Total FIRRTL Compile Time: 2209,9 ms
Total FIRRTL Compile Time: 530,3 ms
End of dependency graph
Circuit state created
[info] [0,002] SEED 1523361961609
chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Error: No implicit clock and reset.
    at chisel3.internal.throwException$.apply(Error.scala:13)
    at chisel3.internal.Builder$.forcedClockAndReset(Builder.scala:209)
    at chisel3.internal.Builder$.forcedReset(Builder.scala:212)
    at chisel3.core.Module$.reset(Module.scala:75)
    at chisel3.core.printf$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Printf.scala:89)
    at chisel3.core.printf$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Printf.scala:89)
    at chisel3.core.WhenContext$$anonfun$1.apply(When.scala:72)
    at chisel3.core.WhenContext$$anonfun$1.apply(When.scala:72)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at chisel3.core.WhenContext.<init>(When.scala:72)
    at chisel3.core.when$.apply(When.scala:32)
    at chisel3.core.printf$.apply(Printf.scala:89)
    at chisel3.core.printf$.apply(Printf.scala:73)
    at taptempo.TapTempoUnitTester.<init>(TapTempoUnitTest.scala:12)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain$$anonfun$2.apply(TapTempoMain.scala:26)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain$$anonfun$2.apply(TapTempoMain.scala:26)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$2.apply$mcZ$sp(Driver.scala:62)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$2.apply(Driver.scala:61)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$2.apply(Driver.scala:61)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcZ$sp(Driver.scala:60)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(Driver.scala:38)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(Driver.scala:38)
    at logger.Logger$$anonfun$makeScope$1.apply(Logger.scala:129)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at logger.Logger$.makeScope(Logger.scala:127)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply$mcZ$sp(Driver.scala:38)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Driver.scala:38)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Driver.scala:38)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:37)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:94)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain$.delayedEndpoint$taptempo$TapTempoMain$1(TapTempoMain.scala:25)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain$delayedInit$body.apply(TapTempoMain.scala:24)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain$.main(TapTempoMain.scala:24)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain.main(TapTempoMain.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:67)
    at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:61)
    at sbt.Run.sbt$Run$$execute$1(Run.scala:51)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:84)
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:248)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (run-main-0) chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Error: No implicit clock and reset.
chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Error: No implicit clock and reset.
    at chisel3.internal.throwException$.apply(Error.scala:13)
    at chisel3.internal.Builder$.forcedClockAndReset(Builder.scala:209)
    at chisel3.internal.Builder$.forcedReset(Builder.scala:212)
    at chisel3.core.Module$.reset(Module.scala:75)
    at chisel3.core.printf$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Printf.scala:89)
    at chisel3.core.printf$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Printf.scala:89)
    at chisel3.core.WhenContext$$anonfun$1.apply(When.scala:72)
    at chisel3.core.WhenContext$$anonfun$1.apply(When.scala:72)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at chisel3.core.WhenContext.<init>(When.scala:72)
    at chisel3.core.when$.apply(When.scala:32)
    at chisel3.core.printf$.apply(Printf.scala:89)
    at chisel3.core.printf$.apply(Printf.scala:73)
    at taptempo.TapTempoUnitTester.<init>(TapTempoUnitTest.scala:12)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain$$anonfun$2.apply(TapTempoMain.scala:26)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain$$anonfun$2.apply(TapTempoMain.scala:26)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$2.apply$mcZ$sp(Driver.scala:62)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$2.apply(Driver.scala:61)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$2.apply(Driver.scala:61)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcZ$sp(Driver.scala:60)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(Driver.scala:38)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(Driver.scala:38)
    at logger.Logger$$anonfun$makeScope$1.apply(Logger.scala:129)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at logger.Logger$.makeScope(Logger.scala:127)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply$mcZ$sp(Driver.scala:38)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Driver.scala:38)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Driver.scala:38)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:37)
    at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:94)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain$.delayedEndpoint$taptempo$TapTempoMain$1(TapTempoMain.scala:25)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain$delayedInit$body.apply(TapTempoMain.scala:24)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain$.main(TapTempoMain.scala:24)
    at taptempo.TapTempoMain.main(TapTempoMain.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last test:runMain for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last test:runMain for the full output.
[error] (test:runMain) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 12 s, completed 10 avr. 2018 14:06:06
```

If I delete 'printf' lines, the testbench works.

Is it possible to print some text and value in testbench with chisel3 iotester ?

The full project is derivated from chisel template github and available on my github repository [TapTempoChisel](https://github.com/Martoni/TapTempoChisel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally I found the problem. It's an **import** problem. In head of source file there is a :

```
import chisel3._
```

It sounds to be in conflict with **printf**. I need this import for **Bool**, then if we just import Bool as it :

```
import chisel3.Bool
```

And remove the **chisel3._** import, that works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to give up the convenient `chisel3._` import:

```scala
System.out.printf("haha, this works\n")
```

This way it calls the Java `System.out.printf` function directly and thus bypasses the Chisel-overridden version of `printf` that fails.

Comment: I'm not sure that a good idea to use this printf. Printf included in chisel will be transmitted to FIRRTL and Verilog no ?

Comment: @FabienM But you want to avoid the Chisel printf, no?